# Paragraph flowing outside of div

Tags: css, html, alignment, footer

I'm trying to make a footer as said here: http://css-tricks.com/left-align-and-right-align-text-on-the-same-line/

The problem is the 2 paragraphs are placed a bit under the footer, as if they where not defined in the div. Here is my code:

```
<div id="footer" style="clear: both;">
  <p class="alignleft">left</p>
  <p class="alignright">right</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
div#footer{
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
.alignleft {
    float: left;
}
.alignright {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden;` on the container `div` to clear floats an don't use `height`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pQjPL/)

CSS

```
div#footer {
   padding: 0px 10px;
   line-height: 20px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That makes them go inside the div, but the div gets pushed down, and i can't scroll to see the whole footer.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski so the issue is solved but why you are not able to scroll? are you using `height`? If yes than don't use it

Comment: i am pushing the footer to the bottom with height = 100% any alternatives?

Comment: i fixed it using min-height instead of height

Comment: obviously, you need to use `min-height` or don't use height at all :)

Comment: unfortunately min-height is not supported by IE6.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski don't worry, IE6 is dead, till how long you going to support it? for that 1 browser you'll write 10 extra lines of CSS, you'll add scripts, etc for supporting that primitive browser, so don't worry, world is going ahead..even Google is not supporting it anymore and will be soon taking out support for IE7 too

Comment: If IE6 support is necessary, this workaround should work:  `height: auto !important; height: 100%; min-height: 100%`.  IE6 doesn't understand the `!important`, so it is ignored.  If archaic browser support is required, it should be noted in the question.

Comment: @cimmanon you don't need to support all browsers, hardly any uses IE6, for a single browser you can't hold back your talent, what's next? I want IE6 to support CSS3 animations, but no it wont, add scripts, add 100 more lines just to support a lame browser...but still thanks for sharing, I am not sure that works as I my work never supported IE6 :p

Comment: @Mr.Alien your anger is misdirected.  I couldn't care less about a dead browser and don't officially support it in my projects if I don't have to, but that doesn't mean I don't know what to do when supporting it is necessary.  Two extra lines of CSS isn't exactly a hardship.

Comment: @cimmanon Am not angry, it's just that using those 2 lines causes more 10 extra lines to add for the other browser, moreover in this case it's 2 lines and not in other, moreover you don't get that professional touch

Answer (score 1):

height value should be auto

CSS

```
#footer{
   height: auto;
   padding: 0px 10px;
   line-height: 20px;
   **word-wrap: break-word;**
}
```